# How to populate request.auth.isAuthenticated once the authentication is done in subsequent route in HAPI framework?

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

```
server.ext('onRequest', (request, reply) => {
  request.context = {
    token: request.headers['X-ACCESS-TOKEN'] || request.headers['x-access-token'],
    clientId: request.headers['X-CLIENT-ID'] || request.headers['x-client-id'],
  };
  request.reply(request.context)
 });
```

When I call the request.reply ,it throws the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call reply and not request.reply, I would write your code like this.

```
server.ext('onRequest', function (request, reply) {

     const context = {
         token: request.headers['X-ACCESS-TOKEN'] || request.headers['x-access-token'],
         clientId: request.headers['X-CLIENT-ID'] || request.headers['x-client-id'],
     };
     return reply(context);
 });
```

Never use an arrow function for request or extension point handlers and always return callback function.